# How to work with boolean attributes in hql hibernate and spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hql

**Here is my hql code :**

```
@Query("select a from Agent where a.visibility = true a order by a.id desc")
public Page<Agent> getAllAgents(Pageable pageable);
```

I want to select all agents that have visibility true.

In my Agent class i have Boolean visibility attribute, that is stored as bit(1) in the database.

**I tried this :** a.visibility = true, ... = 'true', ... is true, = 1, = '1',....

**But get this error :**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: a near line 1, column 74 [select a from com.GemCrmTickets.entities.Agent where a.visibility = true a order by a.id desc]
```

Any suggestions please. Thank you in advance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a typo on your query and the error is very explicit: `unexpected token: a`.

Remove the `a` after `a.visibility = true` and before `order by`. It should work.

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840854/how-to-work-with-boolean-attributes-in-hql-hibernate-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is malformed, it should be:

```
@Query("select from Agent a where a.visibility = true a order by a.id desc")
```

You're binding the entity instance to a variable a, the syntax demands it be declared after the Entity. It's the same in standard SQL.